# Next Steps? Water Spill on Macbook Pro Early 2015 Model A1502

Tags: macbook-pro, damage

Unfortunately some kid on my last flight spilled his drink on my backpack and water seeped into my MacBook Pro via the MagSafe port. I immediately wiped it and shook it to remove any excess water but I did see a small puff a smoke. Once I got home I opened it up, disconnected the battery, and this is what I observed:
The liquid submersed indicator is visible and some damage is noticeable to another component (backlight connector?). The MagSafe charger lights green then amber.
I may take a chance and swap the logic board for a used one off eBay and hope for the best but what do the experts suggest?

[image: bottom cover removed]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Liquid spills are always bad, and there's no real 'recovery'. I don't like the look of the corrosion on those shiny surfaces. If you haven't already, make sure your data is backed up.

*(That's an impressive amount of damage for a drink through a backpack and into a closed MBP, though.)*

If you can get a cheap logic board , and you've had a look at the ifixit.com guide for replacing it, and you're confident you can do it, then you might as well. You can get entire 2015 MBPs on eBay for not so much; though they are quite elderly now. (Unsupported on latest OS, Thunderbolt 2 ports, etc.)

Alternatively, you might want to save your money towards a new(er) model.

At the very least, I'd also look into backpacks that are waterproof. I like [Nordace](https://nordace.com/en/product-category/backpacks/) ones.

Comment: I like how Stack Exchange thinks my question was answered and disables all activity. Anyway their recommendation was lackluster.
I went ahead and purchased a logic board from eBay at 50$. I received it yesterday. Dropped it in and everyone is happy now.